# PQty 4: Deeper unstanding of signals definition

Tags: pyqt4, signals-slots

I have a question concerning the Signal & Slot example on: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Kindly look at the slight modification:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Foo(QObject):

    # Define a new signal called 'trigger' that has no arguments.
    trigger = pyqtSignal()   # Line (1) this is working

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        #self.trigger = pyqtSignal() # Line (2) If i would activate this instead of Line (1) I would get an error

    def connect_and_emit_trigger(self):
        # Connect the trigger signal to a slot.
        self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)

        # Emit the signal.
        self.trigger.emit()

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.

        print "trigger signal received"

if __name__=="__main__":
    a=Foo()
    a.connect_and_emit_trigger()
```

This is still working. However, If I would comment Line (1) and activate Line (2) instead, I get the error message:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  2 2014, 19:48:49) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on xxxx, Standard
>>> Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I don't understand this, because both formulations look similar for me. Who can explain me what is going on here?

Comment: It's quite clearly explained in the documentation you linked to -  i.e. [Unbound and Bound Signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#unbound-and-bound-signals) (first paragraph).

Comment: Ok. If I understand it correctly now than, the assigment in line (1) is only a part of the generation of the signal. Some more processing with `trigger`is done, most likely in `QObject.__init__()`.  Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: No. As the docs say: it's "the same mechanism that Python itself uses to create bound methods from class functions". Calling `Foo.handle_trigger()` is not the same as calling `self.handle_trigger()`, because the first is an unbound function, whilst the second is a bound method (i.e. they're different objects, with different types). Exactly the same thing is true for signals.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Seems that I have to dig a bit deeper in Pythons Class definition. Especially bound and unbound methods. Thank you for your hints on where to search. Greetings, BerndGit